# htaccess simplified and remove need for trailing a slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am writing my very first htaccess and would like help cleaning it up and understanding it. The first issue I am having is with mulitple parameters. my current setup looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]
```

Is there a way to simplify this to handle up to a maximum of 4 parameters with all of them being optional? Which leads me to me next problem that it seems that if you need to have a trailing slash after the parameters unless you are using all 4 parameters.

In short I would like my urls to look like this...

```
http://www.example.com/home
http://www.example.com/home/
http://www.example.com/blog/i-am-a-title
http://www.example.com/blog/i-am-a-title/
http://www.example.com/varable1/varable2/varable3/varable4
http://www.example.com/varable1/varable2/varable3/varable4/
```

I'll appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: Are you looking for a url like this? Are you using MVC pattern?
http://example.com/index.php?controller=blog-title/i-am-a-title

This you can split the controller parameter into sections $parts[0] = "controller", $parts[1] = "method" or something similar, if $parts[1] exists render the single-page.php etc

Comment: @josh I would prefer to have the separate variables if I can, if not I don't mind switching to a controller variable. It wouldn't be to hard to write my code to work with the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is sort of an experiment, it will work as you have said but I believe there may be a better way to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(index\.php|_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)/?)(([^/]*)/?)(([^/]*)/?)(([^/]*)/?)$ /index.php?p1=$2&p2=$4&p3=$6&p4=$8 [L]
```

Basically I am adding an extra group per entry so you can safely exclude a non existent group.

So the first element is required and is `$2`, the second element becomes `$4`, the third element becomes `$6` and the last element becomes `$8`.

`(([^/]*)/?)` this basically means that anything not a `/` that ends or not with `/` for the outer group and inner group anything not a `/`.

Simplified the rule a bit more:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(index\.php|_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|)/?([^/]*|) /index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]
```

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh have a look at the bottom, have simplified a bit more the rule. `([^/]*|)` the basic difference is that matches anything not a `/` or nothing so if the next element is nothing its empty variable and with this we go back to `$1`,`$2`,`$3`,`$4`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind that there will be blank parameters, you can use look-aheads for all of your paramaters:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(index\.php|_modules|css|files|ico|img|js)
RewriteRule ^(?:([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|) index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]
```

The problem with these being optional is that you're rules will loop once, which makes the first capture group `index.php`. To avoid this you need to add `index.php` as part of the exlusion in the condition.

Comment: Could you please help me understand the differance between `(?:([^/]+)|)` and `(([^/]*)/?)` I am not sure which is better or worst to use

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html under "Grouping and Backreferences", it's a non-capture group that allows you to use parens without capturing a group and using a backreference.